# Removing redundant routes from Action Mailbox

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-6, action-mailbox

I am using [Action Mailbox](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_mailbox_basics.html) and have configured it to use Sendgrid. However my routes are now polluted with with inbound end points for other services like Mailgun etc.

They are [defined](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/actionmailbox/config/routes.rb), in the action mailbox gem like so:

```
 post "/postmark/inbound_emails" => "postmark/inbound_emails#create", as: :rails_postmark_inbound_emails
 post "/relay/inbound_emails"    => "relay/inbound_emails#create",    as: :rails_relay_inbound_emails
 post "/sendgrid/inbound_emails" => "sendgrid/inbound_emails#create", as: :rails_sendgrid_inbound_emails

 # Mandrill checks for the existence of a URL with a HEAD request before it will create the webhook.
 get "/mandrill/inbound_emails"  => "mandrill/inbound_emails#health_check", as: :rails_mandrill_inbound_health_check
 post "/mandrill/inbound_emails" => "mandrill/inbound_emails#create",       as: :rails_mandrill_inbound_emails
```

How can I get rid of redundant routes or change them?